# Optimize PHPExcel and script to load file

Tags: php, phpexcel

First of all, clarify that I have seen many topics on the optimization of the reading of the excel file, but having applied some of the solutions and without finding the one that helps me.

I have a system that at a certain point, invokes another php that calls the excel library.
This system, what it does is read an excel file, and record its information in SQL, to then generate PDF.

**index.php**

```
<?php   
    ....
    include("read_excel.php");
    ....
?>
```

I have seen that the load of my index takes approximately 20 seconds, so I have started to dispense parts of my code to see where the problem was, and identify that it was in the file "read_excel.php"

**read_excel.php**

```
﻿<?php

    $sql_host     = "127.0.0.1";      
    $sql_username = "root";    
    $sql_password = "";       
    $sql_database = "payment_locations"; 


    $mysqli = new mysqli($sql_host , $sql_username , $sql_password , $sql_database);

    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    require_once("_library/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");

    $fileName = '_excel/locations.xlsx';

    if (!file_exists($fileName)){
        ?> 
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
            alertify.alert("No exists file");
            </script> 
        <?php 

    }else{
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);

        $date = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('U11')->getValue();

        $dateFormat = date('d/m/Y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date));

        // echo $dateFormat;

        // $dto = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('U11')->getCalculatedValue());

        // echo $dto->format('d-m-Y');

        for ($i = 11; $i <= 31; $i++) {
            if ((float) $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' . $i)->getCalculatedValue() == 0) {
                break;
            }
            $dataExcel[$i]['id_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcel[$i]['payment'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('X' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcel[$i]['period_to'] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('AC' . $i)->getCalculatedValue());
            $dataExcel[$i]['period_from'] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('AD' . $i)->getCalculatedValue());
            $dataExcel[$i]['support'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcel[$i]['location'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcel[$i]['comments'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('AF' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcel[$i]['name_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcel[$i]['ci_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcel[$i]['tel_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcel[$i]['address_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
        }

        foreach ($dataExcel as $dataRow => $value) {
            $dateFormatPeriodTo   = $value['period_to']->format('d/m/Y');
            $dateFormatPeriodFrom = $value['period_from']->format('d/m/Y');
            // var_dump($dateFormatPeriodTo);
            //$dateFormatPeriodTo = date('d/m/Y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($value['period_to']));
            $sql = "REPLACE data_locator (id_locator, payment, period_to, period_from, support, location, comments, name_locator, ci_locator, tel_locator, address_locator) VALUES ({$value['id_locator']}, {$value['payment']}, '$dateFormatPeriodTo', '$dateFormatPeriodFrom', '{$value['support']}', '{$value['location']}', '{$value['comments']}', '{$value['name_locator']}', {$value['ci_locator']}, '{$value['tel_locator']}', '{$value['address_locator']}')";
            // echo $sql;
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        }

        for ($j = 42; $j <= 55; $j++) {
            if ((float) $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' . $j)->getCalculatedValue() == 0) {
                break;
            }
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['id_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['payment'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('X' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['period_to'] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('AC' . $j)->getCalculatedValue());
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['period_from'] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('AD' . $j)->getCalculatedValue());
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['support'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['location'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['comments'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('AF' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['name_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['ci_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['tel_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
            $dataExcelTwo[$j]['address_locator'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I' . $j)->getCalculatedValue();
        }

        foreach ($dataExcelTwo as $dataRow => $value) {
            $dateFormatPeriodTo   = $value['period_to']->format('d/m/Y');
            $dateFormatPeriodFrom = $value['period_from']->format('d/m/Y');
            // var_dump($dateFormatPeriodTo);
            //$dateFormatPeriodTo = date('d/m/Y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($value['period_to']));
            $sql = "REPLACE data_locator (id_locator, payment, period_to, period_from, support, location, comments, name_locator, ci_locator, tel_locator, address_locator) VALUES ({$value['id_locator']}, {$value['payment']}, '$dateFormatPeriodTo', '$dateFormatPeriodFrom', '{$value['support']}', '{$value['location']}', '{$value['comments']}', '{$value['name_locator']}', {$value['ci_locator']}, '{$value['tel_locator']}', '{$value['address_locator']}')";
            // echo $sql;
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);  
        }

    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/datepicker.css">

        <script src="_js/alertify.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/alertify.default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/alertify.core.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/alertify.bootstrap3.css">

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="icon" href="_images/favicon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertify.default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertify.core.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertify.bootstrap3.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

After erasing almost all the code blocks in my read file "read_excel.php", I could see that the line that delayed the execution of my index (which invokes read_excel.php)

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);
```

Once I delete that line, my index loads in milliseconds.

So, my question is, is wrong my way of invoking the excel file that I want to read?

The size of my excel is only 110 KB, I do not think this is a problem, is it?

I'm running my software on a local server, (wamp server 2.5), and Windows 7 64bits. Could be a problem?

I have seen topics where optimizations are suggested for files where a lot of information is processed, but in my case it is a small file and I only use excel blocks (for condition) and this does not seem to be the problem, because the loading speed of my index varies when I eliminate the line:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);
```

Can it be the version of the excel library that I am using?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the "network" tab in the console and see what's going on.

Comment: To debug or find optimization in your scripts I recommend you try out Blackfire.

Comment: PHPExcel last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. The project was officially deprecated in 2017 and permanently archived in 2019.

The project has not be maintained for years and must not be used anymore. All users must migrate to its direct successor PhpSpreadsheet (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) , or another alternative.